# Port 1199 (DMIDI) - What is this service?

Tags: networking, port

I am trying to find out what the DMIDI service is, which apparently runs on port 1199...

From [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=19) it looks like it was registered in 2002 by a Phil Kerr and I can't find any information about it on the Internet. I can't even figure out what `DMIDI` stands for...

Any of you smart admins have any idea?

Comment: Why does it matter? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Search result for [`dmidi phil kerr`](http://openmuse.org/transport/mip_oview.html)

Comment: Thanks @ClassStacker! Can you add that as an answer (Distributed MIDI) so I can accept it

Comment: Just choose David's -- he needs the reputation... ;) Seriously, my comment does not qualify as an answer as per this site's rules.

Comment: @ClassStacker I was writing my answer before I saw your comment :) I had to do a bit of googling ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Iwas pretty sure it was MIDI related but in fact, due to its status, only my second search succeeded. Either way, I had a chance to refresh my memory, you did the professional part, and the OP had the opportunity to have a drink or two while being entertained.

Comment: Note that if you are actually experiencing an issue with a service listening on port 1199, there is no guaranty that it is actually a DMIDI server.  The best approach to discovering its nature, is to use NetStat to find the PID of the service, and investigate it. Linux: `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 1199` or Powershell (as admin): `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING | findstr 1199`. then you can use `tasklist` or `ps` to look at the process itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I am trying to find out what the DMIDI service is, which runs on port 1199

DMIDI is short for Distributed MIDI, and is defined in [IEEE P1639](https://web.archive.org/web/20050206161001/http://dmidi.l4l.ie).

It appears to be a "dead" project.

> 26/10/2004
>
> Due to funding problems work on P1639 has been halted. Many thanks to
> all who helped.
>
> 31/01/2005
>
> P1639/DMIDI has restarted with "avengence".
>
> IEEE P1639 is an Ethernet based protocol wrapper allowing the transmission and reception of MIDI data within a LAN environment.
>
> The goal is to allow low-cost embedded hardware and any PC, be it Linux, Mac or Windows, to transmit and receive MIDI data over Local Area Networks.
>
> For musicians who remember the benefits of the introduction of MIDI with interoperability between different musical instruments, the protocol is aiming for the same level of integration with PC platforms, sequencers, editors and other software and hardware.

**Start of Distributed MIDI Standard—Transmission Over Ethernet and IEEE 802.11**

> The Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) Standards Association has begun work on a standard to extend the reach of Musical Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI) devices by allowing for MIDI transmission over Ethernet and IEEE 802.11 networks. The new standard, IEEE P1639, "Standard for Transmission of Musical Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI) Data within Local Area Networks: Distributed MIDI—DMIDI," should be finalized by the end of 2003. It will retain backward compatibility with existing hard-ware and software under the original MIDI specification, which is now 20 years old.
>
> - The original MIDI standard allowed for a transmission speed of 31.25 kbaud, which was adequate for a musician to control a small number of MIDI devices. DMIDI will use the current Ethernet-based networking infrastructure to carry MIDI data at transmission speeds as great as 10 Gbit/sec. This speed boost will allow for the full use of such sub-protocols as Downloadable Sounds (DLS) and MIDI Show/Machine Control.
> - The new standard will increase the number of addressable devices. The original MIDI specification provided 16 channels for devices. DMIDI will allow for nearly 16 million devices, each retaining the existing 16-channel MIDI structure. DMIDI also adds the ability to send meta-messages for enhanced device control.
> - The standard will optimize DMIDI for low-powered devices. It will specify communication protocols for transmitting MIDI data in Local Area Networks (LANs) and contain low-level protocols and high-level addressing schema for interconnecting MIDI-capable devices over LANs. It also will detail buffering strategies, so traditional MIDI hardware can deal with the higher transmission speeds and so software-based MIDI applications can coexist in the same networking domain as MIDI hardware and still run at full LAN speeds.
> - Anyone with a technical and manufacturing interest in MIDI is invited to join the IEEE P1639 Distributed MIDI Working Group. Others who might want to join include those who seek to explore DMIDI's creative possibilities and those with expertise in Ethernet-based and wireless LAN networking infrastructures.

Source  [Computer Music Journal Volume 27, Number 3, Fall 2003 pp. 13-14](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/47848/pdf)

---

#### Who is Phil Kerr?

> Phil Kerr (philkerr at elec dot gla dot ac dot uk), the person behind DMIDI, is a well-known member of the Linux Audio Developers community. DMIDI is less ambitious than MWPP (and much simpler). Linux and Windows prototypes are available now; Palm and Mac OS prototypes are under development.

Source [Overview of Current Activity in MIDI Over IP](http://openmuse.org/transport/mip_oview.html) (2003)

Comment: Thanks David! I had a process I was running on 1199 for test purposes and wasn't sure what I might be colliding with.

Comment: Starry Internet ISP [says](https://support.starry.com/hc/en-us/articles/360060595913-Port-Forwarding-Port-1199) they block port forwarding on 1199 for security reasons. No idea why.